# Ruby freezes due to unknown character

Tags: ruby

I've experienced a weird problem and would like to know why that happened and how to avoid it next time it shows up. I'm sort of new to Ruby.

I'm currently developing a Rails application that uses Active Admin. One of my index actions looks like this:

```
index do
    selectable_column
    column ('Order') { |p| p.order.number }
    column ('Amount') { |p| p.amount }
    column('Paid at') { |p|p.paid_at }
    # column ('Response code') { |p| p.response_code }
    # column ('merchant code') { |p| p.merchant_code }
    default_actions
end
```

This works perfectly, but if I uncomment the las two lines and reload the page, the application freezes when rendering the view. No logs, no nothing. The ruby process keeps incrementing its memory usage and I'm forced to kill it.

Im using Sublime Text 2 as my editor and Ruby 2.1.1p76.

The weird thing is that removing all the whitespace characters from the lines that cause the problem seem to fix it. I can also add whitespace chars again (using the space bar). This leads me to think it has something to do with weird characters that Sublime puts there somehow (control characters or the like).

Is it possible that Ruby freezes when it finds some special character? Is that documented somewhere? How could I debug such issues?

Thanks

**Edit:**

By showing the whitespaces in Sublime Text, if spotted the offending character (the space between '|p|' and 'p.response_code' is not a whitespace char). 
Anyway, I'd love to know why Ruby freezed due to this character and how did this kind of 'spaces' can appear.

Comment: What character is it, if not a space? Perhaps you should rephrase your question to be closer to what you're asking in the Edit section.

Comment: I don't know what character it is, but it looks like a regular whitespace. Once I enabled the draw_white_space option in Sublime Text (which represents whitespaces as dots) it became clear that it wasn't a whitespace but I have no idea how to know which character it is in Sublime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Invisible Characters and Parsing/Tokenizing

A parser must be able to tokenize your code properly before it can work properly. In Ruby, tokenization and parsing can be inspected with the [Ripper](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) class.

From a parser's point of view, the following two expressions are not the same:

```
{ |p| p.merchant_code }
{ |p|_p.merchant_code }
```

As a self-contained example, consider the following output from the REPL:

```
[2] pry(main)> [1,2].each { |p|_puts p }
NoMethodError: undefined method `_puts' for main:Object
from (pry):2:in `block in __pry__'
```

### One Possible Solution

Non-visible characters created by your editor, or by someone else's editor committing changes to a common code base, can certainly cause these kinds of problems. You might want to search your code base for UTF-8 or UTF-16 characters, or other unexpected character sets, to see if you have some sort of encoding problem in your source code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still don't know how to spot those undesirable characters with Sublime Text, but that's another topic. I'll look into it.